# Not able to use INDIRECT in form control in excel

Tags: excel, combobox, dropdown, excel-indirect, form-control

I am trying to create a combo box using form controls of Developer add-in.

But I want to dynamically change the input range of this form control based on the value in say, cell D4 (I can change the value in D4 with the help of a dropdown). It can take values "A", "B". These are names to following lists.

[image]

I am trying to use function `indirect("d4")` but it is not working and returning a blank box. But when I explicitly write `A` or `B` in the input range then it is working.

[image]

[image]

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is just one way to do it:

Create a named range, let's call it `test`, and enter the following formula for the named range:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(D4,A1:B1,0),A2:A6,B2:B6)
```

Then in your form control set the input range to

```
=test
```

*et voila*.